# Promote new Exchange server, decommission old - process

Tags: exchange-2007, migration

I've got a new server that I want to use to replace an existing (older generation hardware) server, both of which are hosting Windows 2008 DC + Exchange 2007.

Both machines are currently running side by side, with all the mailboxes moved to the new server, and the MX records moved to the new as well.

In order to remove the old server from Exchange functionality and completely remove it from the DC, I need to uninstall exchange and run DCPromo.

In which order should I do this to ensure that all the functionality and roles are working on the new server, and the old server can be effectively shutdown without issue?

Do I:

- promote the new machine to DC controller via dcpromo, then
- remove exchange from the old machine, then
- remove the old machine from the domain via dcpromo

Or should these steps be performed in a different order?

I've attempted disabling services on the old machine, and unchecking the Global Catalog box from the old server in AD Sites and Services, but this caused issues where OWA could not find a Global Catalog (may have been related to services on the new machine being disabled by one of the above changes, or something unrelated)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *must* promote your new DC before removing your old DC. Eitherwise you'll end up without a DC and that will suck.

You should:

1. Promote your new DC (`dcpromo`)
2. Make sure your new DC is a Global Catalog
3. [Move all roles from the old DC to the new DC](https://serverfault.com/questions/312164/things-to-check-prior-to-moving-all-fsmo-roles-to-a-new-domain-controller-before)
4. Remove Exchange from the old server
5. Demote the old DC (`dcpromo` - also remember to remove it as a DNS server from all DHCP scopes and any statically configured machines)

#4 and #5 can actually be done in any order; they should not interfere with each other.