# Transfer a Domain Controller role with its global catalog to another server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [things to check prior to moving all FSMO roles to a new domain controller before decommission original old domain controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/312164/things-to-check-prior-to-moving-all-fsmo-roles-to-a-new-domain-controller-before)

I'm trying to looking for a post in Technet about how to transfer a domain controller role  with its global catalog to another server with Active Directory in Windows Server 2008 R2. But I haven't have lucky to find that information.

Could help to provide a link or tutorial about how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a master catalog? Do you mean global catalog?

Comment: @MDMarra I meant global catalog, sorry for the terminology

Answer (score 3):

This is the general procedure for migrating domain controllers:

1. Install the new server and join it to the domain.
2. Promote it to Domain Controller (`dcpromo /adv`). Make sure that the `Global Catalog` option is selected.
3. Transfer all FSMO roles from existing DC to new DC (`netdom query fsmo` will show you which server holds which FSMO role, [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324801) explains how to transfer each of them).
4. Give the servers some time to replicate directory information.
5. Migrate other services (e.g. DHCP) as appropriate.
6. Demote the old DC (`dcpromo /adv`).
7. Remove the old Server from the domain if it's to be decommissioned.

If old and new DC have the same operating system version, that's all you have to do. However, if the old DC runs Windows Server 2008 and the new DC will be running Server 2008 R2, you **must** extend the AD schema first. Copy the folder `\SUPPORT\ADPREP` from the Windows Server 2008 R2 DVD to the old DC and run the following commands:

```
adprep /forestprep
adprep /domainprep
adprep /domainprep /gpprep
adprep /rodcprep
```

See [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731728%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for details about the `adprep` command. Run **all 4** commands, even if you don't plan to run RODCs. After the commands completed successfully, you can proceed with step 2 from above.